# Azure stack hub api date on iso 8601

Tags: python, azure, date, datetime

I am developing a simple script to the Azure Stack API that would return performance metrics for a defined time slot. In my case I am building the call for 72 from now.
The date needs to be in ISO 8601 and I am building the date as follows:

```
reportedEndTime = datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')
reportedStartTime_aux = datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc) - datetime.timedelta(hours=72)
reportedStartTime = reportedStartTime_aux.isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')
```

The time I tried is with milliseconds and seconds just to avoid having the decimals in the time.

Finally, replacing ':' by '%3a' and '+' by %2a as per Azure Stack's documentation:

> Start time of the query. The value for DateTime should be in UTC and at the beginning of the hour; for example, 13:00. For daily aggregation, set this value to UTC midnight. The format is escaped ISO 8601; for example, 2015-06-16T18%3a53%3a11%2b00%3a00Z, where colon is escaped to %3a and plus is escaped to %2b so that it's URI friendly.

```
str_start=reportedStartTime.replace('+','%2b').replace(':','%3a')
str_end=reportedEndTime.replace('+','%2b').replace(':','%3a')
```

I have also tried replacing '+00:00' by 'Z'

The uri formed is the following:

```
https://adminmanagement.example.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionID}/providers/Microsoft.Commerce.Admin/subscriberUsageAggregates?reportedStartTime=reportedStartTime=2021-11-06T08%3a07%3a32.327%2b00%3a00&reportedEndTime=2021-11-09T08%3a07%3a32.327%2b00%3a00&aggregationGranularity=Hourly&api-version=2015-06-01-preview
```

and it returns this error. I am not sure what is wrong with the date format that I building.

```
{"error":{"code":"BadQueryString","message":"The reported date time 'reportedStartTime=2021-11-06T08:07:32.327+00:00' is not in ISO 8601 format(YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ)."}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: seems they want a Z after the UTC offset; `2015-06-16T18%3a53%3a11%2b00%3a00Z` would be `2015-06-16T18:53:11+00:00Z` in normal notation. So you'd have to prepend the Z; `.isoformat(timespec='milliseconds') + 'Z'`

Comment: I have done that as well

Comment: did you also try without the milliseconds, as in the example from the docs?

Comment: Yes I have used seconds instead of milliseconds and the url is as follows

`https://adminmanagement.azure.com/subscriptions/subscriptionId/providers/Microsoft.Commerce.Admin/subscriberUsageAggregates?reportedStartTime=reportedStartTime=2021-11-06T10%3a14%2b00%3a00Z&reportedEndTime=2021-11-09T10%3a14%2b00%3a00Z&aggregationGranularity=hourly&api-version=2015-06-01-preview`

The return error is similar
`{"error":{"code":"BadQueryString","message":"The reported date time 'reportedStartTime=2021-11-06T10:14+00:00Z' is not in ISO 8601 format(YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ)."}}`

Comment: Found the issue, 
`/subscriberUsageAggregates?reportedStartTime=reportedStartTime=2021-11-06T10%3a14%2b00%3a00Z` has a duplicated param name _reportedStartTime_ I was focused on the date and how I created that format without looking at the hardcoded url/param. 
@MrFuppes, thanks for looking at it

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the url has a duplicate param name called as **reportedStartTime**.